# ASP.NET SOAP Service XXE

Tags: .net, web-service, asp.net, xxe

Is it possible to do any type of XXE in a service developed using default C# SOAP service framework?

I ask because any type of XXE payload I try to add, even XML header, whatever I add before SOAP envelope, I get 400 bad request back from server.

Is it even possible to do XXE in .NET SOAP webservice? If yes, please give me some examples. If not, please confirm so I can move on and test for other vulnerabilities. Thank you